# grpc-java auth forwarding with interceptors: ServerInterceptor Context doesn't propagate to ClientInterceptor

Tags: grpc-java

I'm writing a gRPC server in java that needs to forward client credentials in making gRPC calls to other services. Following the approach recommended on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/4212#issuecomment-373026999), I add both a server interceptor and a client interceptor. The server interceptor copies values out of the grpc header `Metadata` and into the `Context`; the client interceptor copies those values out of the Context and into the outgoing grpc header `Metadata`. (Code is at bottom.)

Most of this is working. The server interceptor is successfully finding the header fields I care about, loading them into the `Context`, and when I inspect the `Context` inside the actual RPC handler method (in my `FooServiceGrpc.FooServiceImplBase` subclass), I find the fields populated as expected. What is *not* working is, inside the client interceptor, I'm looking at a different `Context` and it has none of the values I copied from `Metadata`.

The code that's doing what I want (server interceptor, handler) are all in the same thread, `grpc-default-executor-0`, while the client interceptor is running in `grpc-default-executor-1`. That feels related: the `Context` is understood to be thread-local. It's distinctly possible that the issue here is I'm using the async stub for my outgoing RPC client.

Do folks know about how these `Contexts` are managed, and how I can ensure that the values I set in my server interceptor are available in my client interceptor(s)?

---

```java
enum GrpcMetadataPassthrough {

  AUTHORIZATION("authorization"),
  CONTENT_TYPE("content-type"),
  GRPC_ACCEPT_ENCODING("grpc-accept-encoding"),
  USER_AGENT("user-agent");

  final String key;
  final Metadata.Key<String> metadataKey;
  public final Context.Key<String> contextKey;

  GrpcMetadataPassthrough(String key) {
    this.key = key;
    this.metadataKey = Metadata.Key.of(key, Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
    this.contextKey = Context.key(key);
  }

  Context copyMetadataToContext(Metadata requestHeaders, Context context) {
    String value = requestHeaders.get(metadataKey);
    if (value != null) {
      context = context.withValue(contextKey, value);
    }
    return context;
  }

  void copyContextToMetadata(Context context, Metadata headers) {
    String value = contextKey.get(context);
    if (value != null) {
      headers.put(metadataKey, value);
    }
  }
}
```

```java
class AuthContextServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
      final Metadata requestHeaders,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    Context current = Context.current();
    for (GrpcMetadataPassthrough field : new GrpcMetadataPassthrough[]{
        GrpcMetadataPassthrough.AUTHORIZATION,
        GrpcMetadataPassthrough.CONTENT_TYPE,
        GrpcMetadataPassthrough.GRPC_ACCEPT_ENCODING,
        GrpcMetadataPassthrough.USER_AGENT}) {
      current = field.copyMetadataToContext(requestHeaders, current);
    }
    return Contexts.interceptCall(current, call, requestHeaders, next);
  }
}
```

```java
class AuthContextClientInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {
  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(
      MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
    return next.newCall(
        method,
        callOptions.withCallCredentials(
            new CallCredentials() {
              @Override
              public void applyRequestMetadata(RequestInfo requestInfo, Executor appExecutor, MetadataApplier applier) {
                appExecutor.execute(
                    () -> {
                      try {
                        Metadata headers = new Metadata();
                        for (GrpcMetadataPassthrough field : new GrpcMetadataPassthrough[]{
                            GrpcMetadataPassthrough.AUTHORIZATION,
                            GrpcMetadataPassthrough.CONTENT_TYPE,
                            GrpcMetadataPassthrough.GRPC_ACCEPT_ENCODING,
                            GrpcMetadataPassthrough.USER_AGENT}) {
                          field.copyContextToMetadata(Context.current(), headers);
                        }
                        applier.apply(headers);
                      } catch (Throwable e) {
                        applier.fail(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withCause(e));
                      }
                    });

              }

              @Override
              public void thisUsesUnstableApi() {}
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to create an executor to copy metadata to context, pass the executor through `Context.currentContextExecutor()` so you would be able to observe the same context when you get the metadata out.

https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Context.html#currentContextExecutor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-